# How to get value without knowing key in map function of react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have pretty clear object and map function in react js.

My data is in state variable this.state.response

```
response = [
    {
        "number": "CA1",
        "name": "Kiran",
        "type": "Books",
        "contact": "98989898"
    },
    {
        "number": "CA2",
        "name": "Rahul",
        "type": "MP3",
        "contact": "98989898"
    }
]
```

& Here I want to print data in table in react jsx file

```
{
    this.state.response !== "" &&
    this.state.response.map((data, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>
            {
                console.log("Here I want to print data");
            }
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    ))
}
```

I can access each data with *{data.number}* or *{data.name}*

But I dont know the keys like number, name or type in the response which is dynamic data from API.

So my question is how can I create multiple  with data value from response.

Answer (score 3):

`Object.entries` will return all the properties and values as keys and values in array,
`Object.keys` will return all the properties in array and
`Object.values` will return all the values in array

```
this.state.response.map((data, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>
            {
                console.log(Object.entries(data));
                Object.values(data).map(d => <td>{d}</td>);
            }
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Is there any code to directly show field values in <td> ? Thank you for your response btw

Comment: Yup, I updated the code, this will show values only.

Answer (score 1):

Use method Object.keys() to get an array of keys in the given object

```
{
    this.state.response !== "" &&
    this.state.response.map((data, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>
            {
                Object.keys(data) //Returns array of all keys: Array ["number", "name", "type", "contact"]
            }
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    ))
}
```

Comment: I am trying to complete my requirements, will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values` will `loop` through the number of values in the `data` and show them in `td` tag

```
this.state.response.map((data, i) => (
    <tr key={i}>
       <td>{i+1}</td>
       {Object.values(data).map(val => {
             return <td>{val}</td>;
           })
        }
    </tr>
));
```

To get the `keys` along with the `values` you'll have to use `Object.entries`.

```
    this.state.response.map((data, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
           <td>{i+1}</td>
           {Object.entries(data).map(val => {
             return <div>
               <td>{val[0]}</td><td>{val[1]}</td>
               <br />
             </div>
               })
            }
        </tr>
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys from an object using [`Object.keys(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). After that you can loop through the keys and access each key on each object.

```js
class ResponseTable extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    response: [{
      "number": "CA1",
      "name": "Kiran",
      "type": "Books",
      "contact": "98989898"
    }, {
      "number": "CA2",
      "name": "Rahul",
      "type": "MP3",
      "contact": "98989898"
    }]
  };
  
  render() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.state.response[0]);
  
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>{keys.map(key => <th key={key}>{key}</th>)}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.response.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              {keys.map(key => <td key={key}>{item[key]}</td>)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ResponseTable />,
  document.querySelector("#response-table-container")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="response-table-container"></div>
```

Note that this solution uses `this.state.response[0]` to determine the keys. If this array can be empty you might need to set up some sort of default, because `this.state.response[0]` will evaluate to `undefined`.

In this scenario one solution would be use an empty object as default:

```
Object.keys(this.state.response[0] || {})
```

Which will return an empty array if response is empty. But you could also render an message notifying the user of the empty results.

```
if (this.state.response.length == 0) {
  return <div>Nothing found</div>;
}
```

These are just examples and you'll have to determine yourself what you want to do in such a scenario. If this scenario never occurs you don't have to handle it.